# Safari Chrome form with no action not working

Tags: forms, google-chrome, safari, action

I'm building an app using Django and jQuery. For in some forms in the HTML I make AJAX calls using only jQuery so I put the form with action="#" method="" and have.

When I press the submit button in FF it works fine, nothing gets reloaded and the ajax call is made. In Chrome and Safari, however, the page get's reloaded and re-requested from the server.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

As much as possible, Webkit and Opera try to follow the HTML5 draft. Currently, the [form submission section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission) says that actions that start with HTTP(S), even if the `action="#"` or `action=""`, will cause a navigate, which should cause a new page load when the new GET parameters are added. If you want to prevent the page from reloading, you'll have to add a submit handler that prevents the default action by returning false or saying `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if leave action and method out? You shouldn't need those anyways if you're submitting with an ajax call.